# How to design a system that deals with incrementing registration number in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB how to create Registration number ?

I need auto incrementing value but MongoDB doesn't have auto increment by default (risk in case concurrency failure),
so how to do it?

Eg. current registration no : 1
now when I insert a new record this must be 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: Does the value need to be increasing and without gaps or is it ok if there is a gap as long as the values are increasing?

Comment: for invoice number there must not be any gap

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to achieve this, there are a few solutions for certain situations.

For example if you're using Mongo Realm you can define a DB trigger, I recommend following this [guide](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/triggers-tricks-auto-increment-fields/?_ga=2.127152013.140580236.1657121294-1583095054.1620125856)

If you're using `mongoose` in your app there are certain plugins like [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) that do it for you.

The way they work is by creating an additional collection that contains a counter to be used for every insert, however this is not perfect as it your db is still vulnerable to manual updates and human error. This is still the only viable solution that doesn't require preprocessing of some sort, I recommend to also create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#:%7E:text=A%20unique%20index%20ensures%20that,the%20creation%20of%20a%20collection.) on that field to at least guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: So we need to do it another way i think. using a counter by locking from c# and the requests are to be processed through a server so atomic. i means the server will hold the next request untill current one is not completed.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that

FindOneAndUpdate is atomic

```
static public async Task<long> NextInt64Async(IMongoDatabase db, string seqCollection, long q = 1, CancellationToken cancel = default)
{
    long result = 1;
    BsonDocument r = await db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("seq").FindOneAndUpdateAsync<BsonDocument>(
        filter: Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", seqCollection),
        update: Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Inc("seq", q),
        options: new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>() { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, IsUpsert = true },
        cancellationToken: cancel
    );
    if (r != null)
        result = r["seq"].AsInt64;
    return result;
}
....
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Person() { Id = await NextInt64Async(db, "person"), Name = "Person" + i });
```

Find full example here
https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/02%20-%20Intermediate/InsertLongId.cs

Comment: Unlikely, but not impossible: if a number is retrieved using `FindAndModify`, but the insert fails, there is a gap. A transaction could fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid gaps, you can use the following approach that involves only updates to a single document that are atomic:

First, you pre-fill the invoice collection with a reasonable amount of documents (if you expect 1000 invoices per day, you could create the documents for a year in advance) that has a unique, increasing and gap-less number, e.g.

```
[
  { _id: "abcde1", InvoiceId: 1, HasInvoice: false, Invoice: null },
  { _id: "abcde2", InvoiceId: 2, HasInvoice: false, Invoice: null },
  { _id: "abcde3", InvoiceId: 3, HasInvoice: false, Invoice: null },
  ...
]
```

There should be a unique index on `InvoiceId` and for efficient querying/sorting during the updates another one on `HasInvoice` and `InvoiceId`. You'd need to insert new documents if you are about to run out of prepared documents.

When creating an invoice, you perform a `FindOneAndModify` operation that gets the document with the lowest `InvoiceId` that does not have an `Invoice` yet. Using the updates, you assign the `Invoice`, e.g.:

```
var filter = Builders<Invoice>.Filter.Eq(x => x.HasInvoice, false);
var update = Builders<Invoice>.Update
  .Set(x => x.HasInvoice, true)
  .Set(x => x.Invoice, invoiceDetails);
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Invoice>()
  {
    Sort = Builders<Invoice>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.InvoiceId),
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After,
  };
var updatedInvoice = await invoices.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, options);
```

`FindOneAndModify` returns the updated document so that you can access the assigned invoice id afterwards.

Due to the atomic execution of `FindAndModify` there is no need for transactions; gaps are not possible as always the lowest `InvoiceId` is found.